# nginx: proxy_bind to random ip address in range

Tags: nginx, proxy, http

I'm trying to configure a proxy in nginx that binds all proxied request to a random IP address in a specific range. Every proxied request will originate from a different IP address.

I currently have the configuration posted below. However, for some reason nginx isn't listening on port 80 even though the configuration loads just fine. I get connection refused when trying to access the server.

Am I going about this wrong?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name my.server.name;

  location / {
    # proxy all requests to destination
    proxy_pass https://destination;

    # generate random IPv6 between IPv6Prefix::0 and IPv6Prefix::13
    set_by_lua_block $ip { return 'IPv6Prefix::' .. string.format('%x', math.random(0, 19)) }
    proxy_bind $ip;

    # keep connections alive
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To test whether Nginx is listening on port 80, on the same server, you can run:

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep nginx
```

You should get back a result matching Nginx, reporting it listening on port 80. If that works, the next test is to access Nginx from inside the server via HTTP:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1
```

If that works, the issue is a firewall or other networking issue. Check that the firewall on the server allows incoming HTTP, if you are running one. If you are in a environment like AWS, you may also need to check that our Security Group rules are also allowing incoming HTTP requests to the host.

Regarding your proxy code, note that proxy bind is for binding to *local* IP addresses. That is, IP addresses which are already assigned to the machine. For this to work, it seems you need some additional code to run before Nginx starts, which assigns every IP address in the target range to your machine, assuming your OS and networking hardware support that.

For that to be a safe operation, all the IP addresses need to also be unused, as two machine broadcasting that the have the same IP address can cause problems.